# How to apply Chain Rule with differentials in Matrix Derivatives?

Tags: matrix-calculus, chain-rule

@Steph had kindly answered my [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4312210/995581), but I can't work out the math.

He said that "The correct way to apply chain rule with matrices is to use differentials", and provided the answer to $\partial E \over \partial W_4$.

OK, let's suppose that $\partial E \over \partial A_5$ is known to be $(A_5-R)$, so the answer checked out, no problem.

Now if I want to use the same approach to calculate $\partial E \over \partial W_3$, it should be

$dE={\partial E \over \partial A_5}:dA_5$

$dE=W_4^T{\partial E \over \partial A_5}:dA_4$

$dE=A_3^TW_4^T{\partial E \over \partial A_5}:dW_3$

${\partial E \over \partial W_3}=A_3^TW_4^T(A_5-R)$

The "order" is wrong!

If I want to make it right, then the $A$ has to be in the very front, and the $W$s have to be inserted in the very end for each operation.

Why is that!?

Why the same operation $(dA_5=dA_4W_4)$ will product answers in different positions?

The only "possible", if not "far-fetching", relationship I could find is: Because $A_4$ is "in front", so the answer $(A_4^T)$ will always be in the front, and because $W_4$ is "in the end", so the answer $(W_4^T)$ will always be in the very end.

Is it the right reason, or I'm just thinking too much?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: $\frac{d}{dx}(AB) = (\frac{d}{dx}A)B + A(\frac{d}{dx}B)$, is that what you mean ?

Comment: @Physor I don't think so. It's more like $Xd(AB)=A^TXdB$ or $Xd(AB)=XB^TdA$, why!?

Comment: The double-dot product is defined as
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^nA_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; {\rm Tr}(A^TB) \\
}$$
Using the properties of the trace, you can derived rules to rearrange the terms in such a product
$$\eqalign{
A:(BC) &= (B^TA):C = (AC^T):B \\
}$$
The matrix on each side of the multiplication symbol must have identical dimensions. This analogous to the behavior of the Hadamard product. In fact, the double-dot product is a Hadamard product followed by a summation over all elements.

Comment: @greg Oh, so it's just the basic `Associative` properties of the `Double-dot product`? I'm sorry that I'm not familiar with it, I just looked up the thing in Google, looks like it's something used in `Tensor Calculus`? I'm sorry that's **WAY~** beyond my ability! But thanks anyway for your help! If you could, please be so kind and post it as an answer so I could mark it as the best answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$
\def\SSS{\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^p}
\def\A{A_{ij}}
\def\B{B_{ik}}
\def\BT{B_{ki}^T}
\def\C{C_{kj}}
\def\CT{C_{jk}^T}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\BR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
$To extend my comment above, by expanding the various products
$$\eqalign{
A:\LR{BC} &= \SSS \A\BR{\B\C} \\
\LR{AC^T}:B &= \SSS \BR{\A\CT}\B \\
\LR{B^TA}:C &= \SSS \BR{\BT\A}\C \\
}$$
it is obvious that the sums on the RHS are all identical, therefore the Frobenius (aka double-dot) products appearing on the LHS are likewise identical.

This equivalence could also be arrived at by considering the properties of the trace function when its matrix argument is transposed and/or cyclically permuted.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your question,
from the definition
$$
dE 
= \frac{\partial E}{\partial \mathbf{A}_5}:
d \mathbf{A}_5
$$
with the colon operator
denoting the Frobenius inner product.
Remember that
$\mathbf{A}:\mathbf{B}=
\mathrm{tr}(\mathbf{A}^T \mathbf{B})
$.

Consider the 'simple' product layer :
$\mathbf{A}_5=\mathbf{A}_4 \mathbf{W}_4$,
you can either obtain
$$
dE 
= 
\frac{\partial E}{\partial \mathbf{A}_5}:
\mathbf{A}_4 (d \mathbf{W}_4)
=
\mathbf{A}_4^T
\frac{\partial E}{\partial \mathbf{A}_5}:
d \mathbf{W}_4
$$
or
$$
dE 
= 
\frac{\partial E}{\partial \mathbf{A}_5}:
(d\mathbf{A}_4) \mathbf{W}_4
=
\frac{\partial E}{\partial \mathbf{A}_5}
\mathbf{W}_4^T:
d \mathbf{A}_4
$$

Thus by identification
$$
\frac{\partial E}{\partial \mathbf{W}_4}
=
\mathbf{A}_4^T
\frac{\partial E}{\partial \mathbf{A}_5}
,\quad
\frac{\partial E}{\partial \mathbf{A}_4}
=
\frac{\partial E}{\partial \mathbf{A}_5}
\mathbf{W}_4^T
$$
This gives you the backpropagated gradient of the loss function.
Note how the matrices come either on the left or the right.
This is why your derivation is wrong from the second line.
As shown in Greg's comment,
these facts are easily deduced from the trace properties.